# Keyboard shortcut to open Mac menu

Tags: keyboard, menu-bar

Is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to open the Apple menu? The closest thing I can find in the [Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)is pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> which opens the help menu (if one exists).

I'm open to suggestions that incorporate the use of third party apps like BetterTouchTool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Ctrl-F2 will move focus to the menu bar, placing it initially on the Apple Menu (but not opening it—you'll then have to press Space or down arrow to do that).

You can find/change this shortcut in the Keyboard System Preferences > Shortcuts tab > Keyboard section.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!